# Calling a function from a directory duplicated in the package name?

Tags: rust

In the following structure, I want to call the function `init()` written in `seed.rs` in `example.rs`.
At this time, it should be enough to declare `use::apple::seed::init;`. (In `apple/lib.rs`, it is declared as `pub mod seed;`.

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── app
│ ├── Cargo.toml
│ ├── diesel.toml
│ ├── init.sh
│ ├── migrations
│ ├── src
│ │ ├── bin
│ │ │ ├── example.rs
│ │ ├── model
│ └── test_cases
├── core
│ ├── apple
│ │ ├── Cargo.toml
│ │ ├── lib.rs
│ │ └── seed.rs
```

However, since the package apple with the same name is declared in `Cargo.toml`, it is targeted at this package and cannot be called.(The init function does not exist in this package.)

Is there a workaround to avoid calling the package with the same name?
(The actual package names is not apple.)

There is a directory in core similar to apple, and functions in it could be called with `example.rs`.

Also, `init()` could be used elsewhere.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your project structure relevantly is — the source `mod`s and the `Cargo.toml` very much affect what needs to be done to get the access you want. Can you please create a minimal complete project that demonstrates the problem you're having when compiled, and post the text of _all_ its files (all `Cargo.toml`s and all source files)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I solved the problem by adding the following to app/Cargo.toml

`apple = { path = "... /... /core/apple" }`